# Web3.js устарел?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, web3.js

Начал изучать web3.js, но на сайте в консоли ошибка - `MetaMask no longer injects web3`.
Как я понял, metamask больше не работает с web3.js. То есть по сути web3.js больше никому не нужен?) Ну, может, есть какие-то похожие инструменты, как метамаск, но лисичка-то самая популярная.

Как я понял, сейчас нужно учить ethers.js. Да?

Comment: устарела версия, которую метамаск встраивал на страницу.

Comment: Что это значит? В плане разработки на web3.js

Comment: Это значит, что для встраивания они использовали старую версию и отказались от нее. Теперь не встраивают: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#provider-migration-guide

Comment: В принципе - ничего не значит. Ты можешь продолжать использовать эту библиотеку если хочешь, либо любую другую.

Comment: Твоё мнение, что сейчас лучше учить, использовать - web3.js или ethers.js

Comment: web3.js не устарел, на github даже обновление всего 2 недели назад последнее было. Metamask перестал его использовать году в 2019/2020, но решение вашей проблемы есть в офф мануале https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html

Comment: @Colorkat, в принципе без разницы. Можешь просто [сравнить чем отличаются](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/62028/26383) и выбрать что больше понравилось

Answer (score 1):

Это не так, просто, MetaMask более не подгружает автоматически `web3.js` на веб-страницу

> MetaMask no longer injects web3. For details, see: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3

Более подробно о миграции вы можете [прочитать в документации](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3). Если нужно срочно воспроизвести код, использующий устаревшую версию MetaMask, вы можете поставить расширение [из этого github репозитория](https://github.com/MetaMask/legacy-web3-extension)